# compare 2 Arc pointer

Tags: c++, rust

In C++, you can compare 2 pointers, as comparing pointers is equavalent to comparing 2 addresses:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Dummy {};

int main() {
    auto a = Dummy{};
    auto b = Dummy{};
    const Dummy* ptr_a = &a;
    const Dummy* ptr_b = &b;

    if (ptr_a > ptr_b) {
        cout<<"ptr_a > ptr_b\n";
    } else {
        cout<<"ptr_a <= ptr_b\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly I want to compare 2 `Arc` pointer in Rust:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Dummy {}

fn main() {
    let ptr_a = Arc::new(Dummy {});
    let ptr_b = Arc::new(Dummy {});
    
    if ptr_a < ptr_b {}
}
```

only to get error:

```
binary operation `<` cannot be applied to type `Arc<Dummy>`

an implementation of `PartialOrd` might be missing for `Dummy`
  --> src/main.rs:3:1
```

Apprently `ptr_a < ptr_b` is comparing the contents they point to, not the memory addresses.

How do I compare 2 Arc pointer without implementing trait `PartialOrd` for the struct it points to?

---

more background: I need a function to order 2 `Arc<Dummy>` variables without changing predefined struct `Dummy`. It can be semantically meaningless (e.g. compare their addresses) but it has to be deterministic when calling.

Comment: "In C++, you can compare 2 pointers" - Actually, you can't do that. You are comparing (not just for equality) two pointers that do not point into the same array. This is undefined behavior. You need to use `std::less` or cast to `uintptr_t` for comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extract a raw pointer from the `Arc`, using [`Arc::as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.as_ptr). Those can be compared by their address:

```rust
if Arc::as_ptr(&ptr_a) < Arc::as_ptr(&ptr_b) {}
```

If you want to only test *equality*, you can use [`Arc::ptr_eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.ptr_eq):

```rust
if Arc::ptr_eq(&ptr_a, &ptr_b) {}
```